# How to get cookies and do for each in a loop

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, foreach

I need to create a foreach loop for every name in the cookie and check the checkboxes again.

**Cookies**:

```js
document.cookie = "btnname=btnname1#btnname2#btnname3";
document.cookie = "otherstuff=...";
```

I've tried:

**Code**:

```js
str = ???
var btnname str.split("#");
btnname.forEach(function)
```

```js
function(){
      document.getElementsByName(btnname).checked = true;
}
```

I don't know how to get only the `btnname` value. How can I get that value?

Comment: Um, `function` is a reserved word... Also, please post valid JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to parse the string correctly, you need to first get the portion following the equals (`=`) sign. After that, just split by your delimiter (`#`).

Once you have all the names, find the elements by that name. You can access fields directly on the form via their name.

```js
const cookieValue = 'btnname=btnname1#btnname2#btnname3';

const applyState = (form, value) => {
  const substr = value.substring(value.indexOf('=') + 1);
  substr.split(/#/g).forEach(id => form[id].checked = true);
};

applyState(document.forms.example, cookieValue);
```

```html
<form id="example">
  <input type="checkbox" name="btnname1" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="btnname2" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="btnname3" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="btnname4" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="btnname5" />
</form>
```

Alternatively, you can query for the input by its name.

```js
const applyState = (form, value) => {
  const substr = value.substring(value.indexOf('=') + 1);
  substr.split(/#/g).forEach(id => {
    form.querySelector(`input[name="${id}"]`).checked = true;
  });
};
```